# Кроссплатформенный календарь

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужен **кроссплатформенный** календарь с возможностью получения из него выбранной даты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Datepicker jquery](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

[Bootstrap 3 Datepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

[Date Range Picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/)